# Unable to make Axios post asynchrounosly from React to Webform

Tags: reactjs, webforms, axios

I need some help. I have react app, that used axios post to webforms to request / submit some data to backend. A simple axios.post("path", data) call.

On first axios post, the response will take around 20second (for data to response back) 
Before the first post finished, user are able to click around other react component, which some component will make another axios post that should take around 1 second (small data).

#### Chrome Dev network tab

On chrome dev network, when first post is pending, i can see that second post which was suppose to take only 1 second, instead took 1 sec longer than the first axios post to response back. EG: First axios post 20 second, second axios post took 21 second.

Screenshot of chrome dev network tab -> https://i.stack.imgur.com/KsAmn.jpg

+The one mark in red is second post. 

+Mark in blue is first post.

#### My question

Is the second post only suppose to proceed when the first post is finish? I does not seem to be able to use axios.all in my case, is there any way to make axios post asynchronously? 

EG: When user click on other component when first post is waiting for response, other component post should also only took 1 - 2 second.

I expect the second post which normally only needed around 1 to 2 second to get respond, to be able to run normally even when first post is waiting for respond.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is a browser behaviour. There is a limit on the number of network calls. May be you have more request in progress before the 1 second request.  Axios do support request cancellation, which you can look into to cancel the existing request when you dont need it

Comment: Hi @Panther, from what i understand chrome have limit of 6 network calls. When that do happen, subsequent network call will have a gray bar over them ( stalled ), or do i understand it wrong?

For your suggestion, after checking again, i confirmed that they are the only few network that is currently requesting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue is coming from aspx webform session according to http://hogaf.github.io/archive/2014/11/13/why-asp.net-requests-are-processed-sequentially. I added enablesessionstate to readonly which is something like : <%@ Page EnableSessionState="ReadOnly"> and the request wont get stuck anymore. 

Leaving the answer here in case someone else have the same problem.